# Entity Framework Adding Child Objects to DB

Tags: c#, entity-framework, linq

I am currently stuck on adding a new child entity to my database using lamda queries.
The structure of my database is that `Area` has a one to many relationship with 
`Shifts`

In my seeding database I populate the Shifts while creating the Areas:

```
new Area() 
{
    AreaDesc = "Area 1",
    AreaActive = true,
    AreaCreatedDate = DateTime.Now,
    SHFID = new Shift() 
    {
        StartTime = new TimeSpan (5,30,00),
        EndTime = new TimeSpan (11, 00, 00),
        RequiredResources = 2,
        ShiftDesc = "AM Shift",
        ShiftDayID = 1
    }
}
```

That works fine, where I am struggling and probably due to a simple lack of understanding on entity frameworks abilities is adding a new **Shift** to an existing **Area**.

So far I have the following

```
var AreaVal = _context.Areas.Where(a => a.AreaID == AreaID).ToList();

var Shift = new Shift
{ 
    Area = AreaVal,
    StartTime = StartTime,
    EndTime = EndTime,
    ShiftDayID = model.ShiftDayID,
    ShiftDesc = model.ShiftDesc
};
```

Thinking that once I had the correct **Area** (I have the ID coming from the model) I could load the **Area** and pass it as the **Area** parameter in the **Shift** and entity framework would know what to do.

The Error I get in the parser is:

> Cannot implicitly convert type (Generic.List to
>   Models.Area.

I have also considered going from the other direction using `_context.Areas.Update()` but have been unable to work that one out very well.

### Extra Info, Model Structures

**Shift.cs**

```
public class Shift
{
    [Key]
    public int SHFID { get; set; }
    public TimeSpan StartTime { get; set; }
    public TimeSpan EndTime { get; set; }
    public int RequiredResources { get; set; }
    public string ShiftDesc { get; set; }
    public int ShiftDayID { get; set; }
    public DateTime ShiftExDateStart { get; set; }
    public DateTime ShiftExDateEnd { get; set; }
    public int ShiftExLevel { get; set; }
    public TimeSpan ShiftExStartTime { get; set; }
    public TimeSpan ShiftExEndTime { get; set; }
    public Area Area { get; set; }
}
```

**Area.cs**

```
public class Area
{
    [Key]
    public int AreaID { get; set; }
    public string AreaDesc { get; set; }
    public Boolean AreaActive { get; set; }
    public DateTime AreaCreatedDate { get; set; }
    public List<Shift> SHFID { get; set; }
    public Company Company { get; set;}
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are on the right track.

`AreaVal` needs to be a single entity (`Area`), not a list of entities (`List<Area>`). Then it should work as expected.

Change the line:

```
var AreaVal = _context.Areas.Where(a => a.AreaID == AreaID).ToList();
```

to

```
var AreaVal = _context.Areas.Where(a => a.AreaID == AreaID).Single();
```

Comment: Worked straight away. Thanks heaps!